# connecting to internet in my smartphone

Tags: internet, wifi-hotspot

I have a Note 5 smartphone which I cannot browse any Internet websites using my browser while data is on. But I wonder when using it as a Wi-fi hotspot to share its mobile internet on other smartphone, it works on them! 
I tested two browsers and other apps that use internet connection on my Note 5, but no success.
Any help?

Comment: As per the questions asked on your post in SU; Which browser are you using? Can you connect to the Play Store? Do any other internet connected apps work?

Comment: I answered these questions already. They don't work. I used Chrome and default Samsung browser. Nothing changed!

Comment: Also, no proxy is enabled.

Comment: Did you check your apn settings?

Comment: Yes, I used it earlier with no issue.